# Connect to BLE in IOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

Is it possible to connect to a BLE device without user confirm in Andoird and Ios ??
i want to write and read characteristics in both platform without any confirm and passkey.

My BLE device is a public device that anybody who have my app can connect and use of that.

Comment: No you can not connect BLE device without user confirmation in iOS.

Comment: Yes you can do that from your app. The pairing dialog in iOS only shows up if the peripheral initiates a pairing.

Comment: Hi @Emil , tnx for your answer  , it means that i can programmatically connect to ble in both platform without pairing dialog ??

Comment: Hi @CodeChanger , tnx for your answer , is possible in android ?

Comment: Sure. Both in iOS and Android. You just need the correct bluetooth permissions in your app.

Comment: @Emil for what it's worth I agree that this is totally possible. Bonding is optional step after connection, but characteristic read and write operations can be carried out without bonding.